# jmeter java.io.IOException

Tags: jmeter, ioexception

I have fired https URL on browser and same in jmeter. I want to run few URL's thorugh jmeter but found some difference when i run thorugh jmeter. 
Broswer result-

```
Request URL:https://testurl.com
Request Method:GET
Status Code:302 Found
```

on firing URL, in browser, i get login screen but when i fire same URL through jmeter, its giving exception as below-

```
Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.io.IOException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable"
```

Comment: The error is the same as https://stackoverflow.com/q/42904148 which is not answered yet.

Comment: It can also be a proxy configuration issue, like proxy settings properly set in browser but not in jmeter.

Comment: Are you entering any username or password while logging manually? If not, the application authorizes you using NTLM. You need to add HTTP Authorization Manager to your test plan. If you facing any issues, you need to install the security certificate in bin folder. https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-set-your-jmeter-load-test-use-client-side-certificates

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when the website you target is behind a load-balancer like HA-Proxy or NGinx. Those load balancers use the Host Http header to know to which backend the request must be redirected.

Add the "Host: testurl.com" header to your http request by putting an [Http Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) underneath. I strongly suggest you to record your browser traffic to capture the headers the browser is sending to the remote server.

Comment: Can you share your jmx? Also, try to curl your url with and without the header.